# Timer Task in java?

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have to do the timertask in java. The scenario is: I have to schedule a task for some delay intially. If i have clicked a button it will cancel the current Timer and then it will  reschedule it. How to implement it in java?

when i have used the `cancel()` i can not access the timer again. that is i can not reuse that object. i have declared the `Timer` and `Timertask` as static.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of implementing that is using an **[Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)**.

Let's say you want to schedule a task to run in 30 seconds:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.schedule(new Task(), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

`Task` must be a class implementing `Runnable` interface:

```
class Task implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        // do your magic here
    }
}
```

If you need to **halt** execution of your task, you can use `shutdownNow` method:

```
// prevents task from executing if it hasn't executed yet
scheduler.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: if i schedule a new task then the previous scheduler stops/kills its process??

Comment: It depends on how you use it.

Comment: how to do that?when i shutdown the scheduler object. i can not schedule an another task for that same object?

Comment: `scheduler.schedule()` returns a `Future` object, all you have to do is remember the `Future` and use it's `cancel()` method to remove a single task from the `Executor`, you can then schedule a new task. You don't have to create a new `Executor` every time. Just cancel the old task and schedule a new task when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

As long as they are not declared as `final`, just create new instances.

Comment: i am not declared it as final. just declared as static.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Quartz API](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for this purpose. It would give you more flexibility in clustered env.